# Confused about proving things using compactness

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, solution-verification

Suppose $\{P_n\}$ is a sequence of points in $S$ and $S$ is a compact subset a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ .

Prove that some sequence $\{P_{n_{i}}\}$ converges to a point in S.

So far, What I have come up with is as follows:

1. Since $\{P_n\}$ is contained in a compact set $S$, then any open cover of  of $S$ has a finite subcover and that finite sub-cover will also cover 
   $\{P_n\}$
2. Let us choose the cover $\{B(0,N)\}_{N\in \mathbb N}$ , this covers $S$ and has a finite sub-cover . Then we have $\{P_n\}\subset S \subset B(0,M) $ ( for some $M>0$) and for the subcover is finite,the sequence it is bounded by some $M$.
3. Since  $\{P_n\}$ is bounded by some $M$ , then by the Bolzano- Weierstrass theorem,  a subsequence of  $\{P_n\}$ converges to some point in $S$. Since every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence.

Could you point out my mistakes here or give me an idea on how to prove this? I am just confused as where should I start and how I can start proving things..

P.s. pardon my english as my first language is Dutch.

Comment: HINT: If the sequence has no convergent subsequence, then each $x\in S$ has an open neighborhood $U_x$ that contains no point of the sequence except possibly $x$ itself. These nbhds $U_x$ cover $S$.

Comment: Hi Dr Brian, What is nbhds U <sub> x </sub> ?

Comment: For each $x\in S$ there is an open set $U_x$ that contains $x$ and either contains no point of the sequence, or, if $x$ is a point of the sequence, contains only that one poitn of the sequence.

Comment: I mean but you said nbhds, what does this nbhds abbrievatiaon stand for

Comment: Neighborhood. (Sorry: I thought that it would be clear, since I spelled it out when I first defined the sets $U_x$.)

Comment: why is it that you say if the sequence has no convergent subsequence then each x ∈  must have an open neighborhood of , as even if I have a sequence with a converging subsequence, I can still have an open neighborhood of , since it is converging but is never reaches the converged value

Comment: If every open nbhd of $x$ contained a point of the sequence different from $x$, we could construct a subsequence converging to $x$. If, therefore, we assume that no subsequence converges, every $x$ must have an open nbhd that contains no point of the sequence (unless $x$ itself is one).

Comment: so if we assume that no subsequence converges, the sequence must be something like : 1,1,1,1,1..?

Comment: The proposition you are being asked to prove is Bolzano-Weierstrass.  So, I don't think you should invoke Bolzano-Weierstrass to prove Bolzano-Weierstrass.

Comment: No, because that actually **does** converge, to $1$. The situation is more like having the sequence $\langle 1,2,3,\ldots\rangle$. Of course this can’t actually happen, since $S$ is compact, but that’s more like what would have to happen if the sequence had no convergent subsequence.

Comment: so if the nbhds  cover , then there would be an infinite number of covers? And that would be a contradiction? I think I am tripping over all the notation

Comment: @DougM why do you say that we are proving Bolzano- Weierstrass here?

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass says that any sequence on a closed and bounded region of $\mathbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence.  Heine-Borel says closed and bounded regions of $\mathbb R^n \iff$ compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Now I am just confused because the person below said that my point 3 was okay.. how would you prove this?

Comment: Can anyone show an explicit proof of this? I am still locked up about what something Doug said..

Comment: Hi Dr Brian, could you point out what is wrong with my step 1?

Answer (score 2):

You did a little bit of mistake in showing the sequence is bounded.(rather I would say your idea was right)
Exactly this was the proof which I did during my undergraduate.
observe that since $S$ is compact it is bounded. Hence ${p_n:n\in \mathbb N}$ is a bounded sequence. 
After this Point number 3 is on point !

But I would like to suggest you try to prove it by some other methods as well.

Try to prove the following fact:
[**Any infinite subset of $S\subset \mathbb R^2$ has a limit point in $S$**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2932547/779382)

Comment: S is compact hence bounded right?

Comment: So ${p_n}$ is bounded.

Comment: In the usual metric on $\Bbb R^2$ the set $\{p_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ is bounded, yes; that does not mean that it is compact. And if one is going to apply the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, there is absolutely no point in introducing covers in the first place: in that case one should show first that the sequence is bounded, which the argument in the question does **not** do, and then apply B-W. And if one is going to use the real open cover definition of compactness, the B-W theorem never comes into it at all.

Comment: erm could I ask what metric are we using here , are we not using the usual metric?

Comment: I agree on this with you @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @BrianM.Scott apologies for I didn't notice point 1 carefully .

Comment: @Noobmathematician: No problem, and I’ve upvoted your revised answer.

Comment: What was my mistake in showing that the sequence is bounded? I said because the subcover is finite, it must be bounded, could you help me out here

Comment: Why isn't the set compact here anyone?

Comment: the sequence is bounded indeed true .. but the route you took to say that is not right .

Comment: You can not say the sequence is compact. Instead you can say that the sequence is subset of a compact set hence bounded (this boundedness of compact set needs every open cover has a finite sub-cover)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott in step 2, I did say that the sequence is bounded by some M

Comment: @Noobmathematician What do you think of what Doug M said, he said we are not supposed to use the BOlzano Weierstrass theorem here because that is precisely what we are trying to proof?

Comment: @JosephRock: No, you said that the subcover was bounded by some $M$, a statement that doesn’t really make any sense. On the least unlikely interpretation — that the subcover is contained in some ball about the origin — it’s not even necessarily true.

Comment: @JosephRock: **Doug M** is correct.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If Doug M is correct, isn't the answer provided by noob mathematician wrong since noob uses the Bolzano?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If the subcover is bounded, could i say {Pn} is bounded because the subcover covers {Pn}?

Comment: @JosephRock: Yes, that answer is wrong, apart from the suggestion to look at other approaches. \\ Forget the subcover: you never specified a cover in the first place, so you know absolutely nothing about this subcover save that it’s finite. For all you know it could consist of one open set, $\Bbb R^2$ itself. And forget about boundedness: what you want here is to use compactness directly to prove that the sequence has a convergent subsequence. HINT: If not, each point of $S$ has an open nbhd containing at most one point of the sequence.

Comment: The main thing is . It is the application of Heine-Borel Theorem and then Bolzano Weistrass. You use Heine-Borel to say the compact set S is bounded which implies the sequence is bounded then you use Bolzano to say a convergent subsequence exist. I don't know if you have seen the statement of Bolzano Weistrass theorem and the proof . But to me Bolzano Weistrass is a different statement than what's given here and it is much fundamental than Heine-Borel Theorem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott i see, so if a cover is finite, it doesnt that mean it is bounded? I see, so if every neighborhood is open, then it contradicts that the subset S is closed, and we have a contradiction?

Comment: @Noobmathematician To me, the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem says Every bounded infinite set in R^n has an accumulation point, or every bounded set has a subsequence that converges.. What is it that says to you?

Comment: @Joseph u r r8. And there is no harm in using the Bolzano Weistrass theorem here.

Comment: @JosephRock: No to both. $\{\Bbb R^2\}$ is a finite open cover of every subset of $\Bbb R^2$, but $\Bbb R^2$ is certainly not a bounded set in the usual metric. And the open nbhds that I mentioned are open in $\Bbb R^2$, not in $S$, so they say nothing about whether $S$ is closed, open, or neither. I’m afraid that you’re so far off the mark that I’d do better simply to write up an answer than to keep trying to guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @Brian that is a good idea . But is the editted question ok ? Now ?

Comment: @Noobmathematician: Except that using the B-W theorem completely misses what I strongly suspect is the real point of the exercise, unless the exercise was for some reason actually intended to be utterly trivial.

Comment: @JosephRock: Yes, it now makes sense. And if you’re expected to use the B-W theorem, it’s a perfectly reasonable answer, though in that case the problem really is trivial. I’ll write up a proof that actually uses the compactness of $S$ directly, one that works in any metric space.

Comment: If you want to avoid Bolzano Weistrass then we would need to assume that $\{p_n\}$ has no convergent sub-sequence then work with covers and use compactness and ultimately arrive at a contradiction .

Comment: Hi @Noobmathematician firstly, thank you very much for your edits on my qn and response, secondly I noticed in the edit you used N to be natural numbers, why didn't you use R instead?

Comment: also out of curiosity , why did you change B(0, N) to B(0,M)?

Comment: i mean why must M >0?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof directly from the open cover definition of compactness, one that works in any metric space.

Suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence in $S$, and let $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Suppose that $p$ is a limit point of the **set** $A$; I’ll construct a subsequence of $\sigma$ that converges to $p$.

Let $n_1=\min\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:x_k\in B(p,1)\}$. Now suppose that for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ we’ve already chosen $n_1,\ldots,n_m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $n_1<n_2<\ldots<n_m$ and $x_{n_k}\in B\left(p,\frac1k\right)$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$. $A\cap B\left(p,\frac1{m+1}\right)$ is infinite, so let

$$n_{m+1}=\min\left\{k\in\Bbb Z^+:k>n_m\text{ and }x_k\in B\left(p,\frac1{m+1}\right)\right\}\;;$$

then $n_1<\ldots<n_{m+1}$, and $x_{n_k}\in B\left(p,\frac1k\right)$ for $k=1,\ldots,m+1$, and the recursive construction goes through to produce a subsequence $\langle n_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ of $\sigma$ that converges to $p$.

Thus, we’re done unless $A$ has no limit point. In that case for each $x\in S$ there is an $\epsilon_x>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon_x)\cap A\subseteq\{x\}$. Clearly $\{B(x,\epsilon_x):x\in S\}$ is an open cover of $S$, which is compact, so it has a finite subcover, $\{B(x_1,\epsilon_{x_1}),\ldots,B(x_n,\epsilon_{x_n})\}$, say. $A\subseteq S$, so

$$A=\bigcup_{k=1}^n\big(A\cap B(x_k,\epsilon_{x_k})\big)\;,$$

and therefore $|A|\le n$, since each of the sets $B(x_k,\epsilon_{x_k})$ contains at most one point of $A$. In particular, $A$ is finite, so there must be some $p\in A$ such that $\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:x_n=p\}$ is infinite, and in that case $\sigma$ clearly has a constant subsequence that converges to $p$.

Thus, in every case $\sigma$ has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: here you did not assume that the sequence has no convergent subsequence, is it better to go this path?

Comment: @JosephRock: It turned out to be just as easy to give a direct argument and possibly just a little clearer, so I chose to do so.

Comment: Did you use the fact that every infinite subset of $S$ has a limit point in $S$? . And I think there is a case where $A$ can be finite .  Though it is trivial if $A$ is finite  doesn't it deserve mention in the proof ?

Comment: @Noobmathematician: There is indeed a case in which $A$ is finite; I covered it. No, I did not use the fact that every infinite subset of $S$ has a limit point in $S$.

Comment: Ok yes it works

Comment: @BrianM.Scott why did you use the minimum here? I love this prove but i thinking i am hitting above my weight here haha..

Comment: @JosephRock: I could have used any member of that set instead of the minimum; the minimum is simply a nice, well-defined member of the set, one that can easily be defined.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Could you provide some insight on what you mean by recursive construction?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott when you say minimum, do you mean the set of points that are closest to the center of the Ball that you defiend B(p,1)?

Comment: @JosephRock: In this case you can safely think of it as constructing a sequence of things one element at a time, using a fixed ‘recipe’ to construct each thing in terms of the ones already chosen. (The actual notion is somewhat more general, but what I just wrote is all that’s needed here and gives the correct idea.)

Comment: @JosephRock: No, it’s the minimum of a certain set of natural numbers: it’s the smallest natural number $k$ such that $k>n_m$ **and** $x_k$ is in the open ball $B\left(p,\frac1{m+1}\right)$ centred at the point $p$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott when you used <> vs {} such as in  statement: Suppose that =⟨:∈ℤ+⟩ is a sequence in , and let ={:∈ℤ+}, {} represents a set right? but what about <>

Comment: @JosephRock: The curly braces do indeed represent a set; the angle brackets ($\langle\rangle$) are used to denote a sequence (or an ordered $n$-tuple for some $n$). This is one of several fairly common conventions. More people use parentheses for this purpose, but I prefer to use angle brackets, because parentheses are already used for too many different things.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but when you say   such that > m , we had let 1=min{∈ℤ+:∈(,1)} , nm>n1, but at the same time n1>nm as k=1?

Comment: @JosephRock: Yes, I had to define $n_1$ to get the construction started. After that every $n_k$ is defined by a single rule, the one in the displayed formula defining $n_{m+1}$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but how can nm>n1 and n1>nm at the same time, i wish i understood this proof but there are so many new definitions

Comment: @JosephRock: There’s nothing there that says or implies that $n_1>n_m$; I really don’t understand where you’re getting that idea.